# golang iris return directly template html

Tags: go

```
<!-- file: web/views/hello/index.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{.Title}} - My App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{.MyMessage}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/kataras/iris"
)
func main() {
    app := iris.New()
    // Load the template files.
    app.RegisterView(iris.HTML("./web/views", ".html"))
    // Serve our controllers.
    mvc.New(app.Party("/hello")).Handle(new(controllers.HelloController))
    // http://localhost:8080/hello
    app.Run(
        iris.Addr("localhost:8080"),
        iris.WithoutVersionChecker,
        iris.WithoutServerError(iris.ErrServerClosed),
        iris.WithOptimizations,
    )
}
```

---

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/kataras/iris/mvc"
)
type HelloController struct{}

var helloView = mvc.View{
    Name: "hello/index.html",
    Data: map[string]interface{}{
        "Title":     "Hello Page",
        //"MyMessage": "Welcome to my awesome website",
    },
}
func (c *HelloController) Get() mvc.Result {
    return helloView
}
```

I want to direct return template html. in func (c *HelloController) Get() mvc.View { return helloView } , but Once I do this , The parameters in the template will be empty.  {{.Title}} and {{.MyMessage}} is missing

Comment: What do you mean by "direct return"?

Comment: And: Don't use iris.

Comment: means Return directly.The result I want is 
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{.Title}} - My App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{.MyMessage}}</p>
</body>
</html>
but actual results <html>
<head>
    <title> - My App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Why not use Iris

Comment: @chaoshook Some search results to clear up why you might want to steer clear of Iris: https://ddg.co/?q=site%3Areddit.com%2Fr%2Fgolang+iris&t=h_&ia=web

Answer (score -1):

here are my results from the [mvc/overview example](https://github.com/kataras/iris/tree/master/_examples/mvc/overview), as expected:
[image]

Can I help you with something?